# How to properly implement a Spring Converter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have a Money class with factory methods for numeric and String values. I would like to use it as a property of my input Pojos.

I created some Converters for it, this is the String one:

```
@Component
public class StringMoneyConverter implements Converter<String, Money> {
    @Override
    public Money convert(String source) {
        return Money.from(source);
    }
}
```

My testing Pojo is very simple:

```
public class MoneyTestPojo {
   private Money value;
   //getter and setter ommited
}
```

I have an endpoint which expects a Pojo:

```
@PostMapping("/pojo")
public String savePojo(@RequestBody MoneyTestPojo pojo) {
//...
}
```

Finally, this is the request body:

```
{
   value: "100" 
}
```

I have the following error when I try this request:

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
>   `br.marcellorvalle.Money` (although at least one Creator
>   exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize
>   from String value ('100'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `br.marcellorvalle.Money` (although at
>   least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value ('100')\n at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 8, column: 19] (through reference chain:
>   br.marcellorvalle.MoneytestPojo[\"value\"])",

If I change Money and add a constructor which receives a String this request works but I really need a factory method as I have to deliver special instances of Money on specific cases (zeros, nulls and empty strings).

Am I missing something?

Edit: As asked, here goes the Money class:

```
public class Money {
    public static final Money ZERO = new Money(BigDecimal.ZERO);

    private static final int PRECISION = 2;
    private static final int EXTENDED_PRECISION = 16;
    private static final RoundingMode ROUNDING = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;

    private final BigDecimal amount;

    private Money(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static Money from(float value) {
        return Money.from(BigDecimal.valueOf(value));
    }

    public static Money from(double value) {
        return Money.from(BigDecimal.valueOf(value));
    }

    public static Money from(String value) {
        if (Objects.isNull(value) || "".equals(value)) {
            return null;
        }

        return Money.from(new BigDecimal(value));
    }

    public static Money from(BigDecimal value) {
        if (Objects.requireNonNull(value).equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
            return Money.ZERO;
        }

        return new Money(value);
    }
//(...)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Money` class please?

Comment: @Joel Added the code at the end.

Comment: Thanks.  Just answered

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: @Joel Yes... just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that using the *org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter* only works if the Money class is a  "@PathVariable" in the controller.

I finally solved it using the *com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.StdConverter* class:

I created the following Converter classes:

```
public class MoneyJsonConverters {
    public static class FromString extends StdConverter<String, Money> {
        @Override
        public Money convert(String value) {
            return Money.from(value);
        }
    }

    public static class ToString extends StdConverter<Money, String> {
        @Override
        public String convert(Money value) {
            return value.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I annotated the Pojo with @JsonDeserialize @JsonSerialize accordingly:

```
public class MoneyTestPojo {
   @JsonSerialize(converter = MoneyJsonConverters.ToString.class)
   @JsonDeserialize(converter = MoneyJsonConverters.FromString.class)
   private Money value;
   //getter and setter ommited
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotating your factory method with `@JsonCreator` (from the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` package) will resolve the issue:

```
  @JsonCreator
  public static Money from(String value) {
      if (Objects.isNull(value) || "".equals(value)) {
          return null;
      }

      return Money.from(new BigDecimal(value));
  }
```

I just tested it, and it worked for me. Rest of your code looks fine except for the sample request (`value` should be in quotes), but I guess that's just a typo.

Update 1:

If you're unable to make changes to the `Money` class, I can think of another option - a custom Jackson deserializer:

```
public class MoneyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Money> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

  public MoneyDeserializer() { 
    this(null); 
  }

  public MoneyDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
    super(vc); 
  }

  @Override
  public Money deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
      String value = node.textValue();

      return  Money.from(value);
  }
}
```

Just register it with your `ObjectMapper`.